# Does credit score history matter for credit card application?

Tags: united-states, credit-card

in the US, if one's credit score has only recently improved within a very short time, would one be less likely to be approved than in the case where it had been at the current level for a long time?

Comment: Your credit score is already time-weighted. Your current credit score already takes your credit history into account, so no, your prior credit scores don't matter for any practical purpose.

Comment: time weighing the credit history, i.e. history of missed payments, card usage etc. is different from time weighing your actual credit score. For example, you could have an abysmal credit score for years due to maxing out all credit cards, then one month prior to applying for a mortgage, you pay all cards down and your score will instantly go to excellent.

Comment: If you've maxed out all your credit cards, but aren't missing any payments, you'll have a high credit utilization, but everything else about your credit score will be fine. If you pay them off, your utilization rate drops, and your score goes up a bit. If you _are_ missing payments, your score will be affected a lot more, and that history of missed payments will continue to affect your score. Lenders don't care about your prior score because your _current_ score is already an attempt to encapsulate everything lenders care about.

Comment: That's not true. In fact, they are changing the methodology to FICO 10, which does take past credit scores into account. It's just not clear when it will be implemented. If you think about it, it makes sense. As a lender, why would you be indifferent between someone with a credit score of 750, who had this score for years and someone how had a score of 550 for years and only got to 750 one month ago?

Comment: FICO 10 is a method of calculating your current score... Again, your current score does take your credit history into account. There's no added value for a lender to go back and look at your prior scores when they've got your current score, which already factors that information in. Anyway, it seems like you've already made up your mind, so I don't think there's much value in continuing this discussion.

Comment: No, FICO 10 is not currently being implemented by most lenders, and it won't be before end of 2020. And again, you are confusing credit history and history of credit score. Just do a google search on what FICO 10 does, and you'll understand what I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Lenders care what your credit score is.  They don't care what it was in the past.  If the bank wants applicants to have a 700 credit score for a particular card, they don't care whether you've had that score for a day, a month, or a decade.  They just care what your current score is.

As @NingNing points out in the comments, there are new FICO models coming out that incorporate more historical information about balances and payments into calculating your credit score.  But banks will still just care about the current score not your score from last year.

Answer (score 1):

Credit history can have a substantial impact on your odds of getting approved for a credit card.

Improved credit history doesn't guarantee you'll be approved, and previous poor credit history doesn't guarantee you'll be denied.

Understanding what range your score falls in can help you narrow the options as you decide which cards to apply for.

Answer (score -1):

YES! They do matter. Asking yourself, "Why does my credit score matter?" For a lot of reasons, some of which you may not even be familiar with. A credit score is a way of distilling your relationship with debt down into a 3 digit number. It is used to evaluate your creditworthiness, or how likely you are to pay back the debt.

Whereas

A Credit History is a record of your debts, payment history, and public records. Simply put, the length of your credit history is how long you've used credit. The length of your credit history, or how long you've been using credit, typically accounts for 15% of your total credit score.

I hope I have answered your question as simply as possible.

Comment: This doesn't address the question. The question was whether the _history_ of one's credit score affects their ability to obtain credit